# R Generating random hex color

Tags: r, colors, hex

How can I generate a random hex color with R? I want to create a function that will spit out strings in this format:

```
# "255 0 0"
# "245 32 456"
# ...
```

Would I need to create a function that uses the sample function three times? or is there a simpler way to accomplish this in R? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
paste(sample(0:255,size=3,replace=TRUE),collapse=" ")
```

?